# What happens if Veracrypt encrypted USB device is pulled out without dismounting?

Tags: crash, disk-encryption, filesystem-corruption, veracrypt

Suppose you have a USB device (e.g. pen drive) that is entirely encrypted using Veracrypt (the "Encrypt a non-system partition/drive" option in Veracrypt). If this device is pulled out accidentally while it is Veracrypt-mounted, what level of data corruption is likely to occur, if any? Will the entire device become corrupted (and hence unusable till you reformat it - wiping out *all* data on the device) or would only a few files that were in use when the device was pulled out be corrupted?

I understand, similar questions have been asked earlier regarding individual file containers, but my question is about an entire disk/device that is encrypted.

Answer (score 1):

Where is this warning you talk about? How can I replicate it? Maybe post a screenshot so I can take a look?

To my knowledge, encrypting entire drive should be more secure because the encryption applies to specific blocks of data, and doesnt rely on a single huge file (for example 120 Gb container file) which could get partly corrupted and then the whole container file could become unreadable. If I understand it correctly, with full drive encryption only the specific blocks of data will get corrupted if error occurs, and that will leave you only with one or few files damaged, not the entire thing, so you should be able to successfully mount it without problem and in case of an error only the few files should be damaged.

The only thing that comes to mind, in case of USB flash drives, is that you may be partly avoiding the risk of damaging the container (when yanking the usb stick too soon) because the encrypted container file is mounted and the changes are only being applied internally inside the container so the risk of damaging the container as a whole should be lower. Then again I fail to see, how it would be still less dangerous than encrypting the drive as a whole. Maybe, only if the caching of files is somehow not an issue if you mount a container file off of the USB flash drive, if that is the case by any chance (which I sadly dont know nor can verify) only then it could be more safe than encrypting it as a whole.

I think we won't know for sure unless someone really knowledgeable can explain all the nuances how it works, which is sadly a hard thing to get, even on the official veracrypt forums.

The best advice I can give on this issue is to keep the usb disk in your computer for a while after it finished writing the data, or if you're in a hurry, wait until it writes the data (tmk only data writing is crucial, not reading), then wait 3 to 5 seconds and eject it safely using the notification icon designed to do this operation (it will either eject instantly or after few seconds when it finishes writing the data), and most importantly, always keep periodic backups of your data in case something happens. The worst failure is the mechanical failure of the drive which are quite common in usb flash drives and especially in case of cheap external drives, mainly the HDD external drives. If you want a reliable external drive, then the drives designed for internal use are in my experience more reliable if you pick a good brand, and connect it using usb reduction cable or even a SATA hotplug (motherboard feature) that allows to insert the disk into a drive bay even when the system is running + some drive bays even have a manual switch (or even software controlled one) that kills the 5v and 12V lines, shutting it down to avoid unnecessary run time and spin-ups when the drive is not in use, for example a drive only used for once a month backups or less frequent storage.

Answer (score 0):

Whether or not it is encrypted, one runs the same risk if the disk is *not* dismounted: the file system can become corrupted, or the USB device, in some cases, can be physically damaged so as to be useless. The risks are twofold:

- During the write cycle, part of the data may be cached until committed. If the file system table of contents (TOC) is not updated, then data is written with no location in the TOC.
- Physical damage can occur.

  - Flash memory is sensitive to voltage surges.
  - External hard disks may continue writing as the disk speed changes, destroying the sector layout, or read/write heads can crash onto platters when abruptly powered down.

Though one can often "get away" with yanking out a USB device, eventually, it will stop working.

However, since an encrypted container must be *intact* to be readable, *any* damage to an encrypted container will likely make it *entirely* unreadable (though, **perhaps**, salvageable using forensic tools).

Asking what *specific* damage occurs is like asking, "If I throw a knife in the air and stand underneath, how badly will I be hurt?"

Comment: Interesting. I asked this question because I I was about to encrypt a USB device. Veracrypt (Version 1.25.7) showed a warning message saying something to the effect that entire device encryption carries more risk than creating a file container, as there is a greater risk of losing all data in the former, as compared to the latter. I must admit, I do not know much about these things; hence the question. But your answer appears to suggest that both the methods carry almost the same level of risks?

Comment: They are stating that in either case, everything *inside* the encrypted portion of the drive is more likely to be lost. Of course, if it's the entire drive, that's 100%. If the encrypted container is half the size of the drive, then 50% is gone... and possibly the rest, too, if there's damage.